# Hide overflow-y scrollbars unless needed

Tags: css

Im using `overflow-y` to give my div's vertical scrollbars (obviously yea ik) but doing so keeps the scrollbars on the divs i want to know how to only display the scrollbars when needed

A div in my code looks like this

```js
<div class="panel left" id="terminalPanel">
        <center><h4>Terminal</h4></center>
        <hr>
        <b>Money:</b> <span id="money"></span><br>
        <b>Level: </b><span id="level"></span><br>
        <b>Exp:</b> <progress id="expProgress" value="2" max="3"></progress>
        <center><canvas id="terminalCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas></center>
    </div>
```

the css pertaining to this code is

```css
.left{
        float:left;
        width:25%;
        height:100%;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

also the panel class comes from bootstrap

**EDIT**
here is my page if seeing the issue helps
http://flameforged.altervista.org/games2/ci/

Comment: edit ur css code as: `#terminalPanel{
        float:left;
        width:25%;
        height:500px;
        overflow: auto;
    }`

Comment: I have multiple divs aligned horizontally and they all should have the same behavior

Comment: dont give ur height in percent. use px instead.

Comment: its important that i use percentage wise for max compatibility across different resolutions

Comment: then use 100vh instead of 100%. where vh stands for view-port height

Comment: tht worked!!! Awesome

Comment: good that it worked. u can accept my answer if u dont mind. anyway i have seen ur page. u dont need to scroll horizontally for different small screen sizes. there are css properties to give better look and experience.

Comment: update your answer with the vh method for future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow: auto;`. It works. I have tested. Your page will scroll and not your div if you set your height 100%. Don't use percent in this case. Use px instead. However for those who want screen size compatibility can use vh(Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport) instead of %.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to do it with pure CSS. If you do not hesitate to use javascript, you may check the difference between `scrollHeight` vs `innerHeight` of your `DIV` (suppose you specified a height for that `DIV`) and change the `overflow-y` property accordingly. Below is an example.

```js
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
  $('#div').html($('#div').html() + 'A new line added.<br />');
  if (($('#div')[0].scrollHeight > $('#div').innerHeight()) && ($('#div').css('overflow-y') === 'hidden')) {
    $('#div').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}, 100);
```

```css
#div {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Comment: Would like to avoid javascript as the game is running on javascript and ive got about 7000 lines already

Answer (score 0):

Set the `overflow-y` property to `auto` : `overflow-y: auto;`

Edit:

try changing the css to:

```
#terminalPanel{
        float:left;
        width:25%;
        height:100%;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

If that doesnt work try :

```
.left{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto !important;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what u mean

Comment: Can you edit your question and write the code you have tried